# UIDatePicker changing size

Tags: iphone, ios, uidatepicker

How do I change the size of a UIDatePicker? Setting the frame doesn't seem to work. It only changes the size of the black background on a UIDatePicker, not the actual components within the Picker.

Comment: You can change the width, but not the height from what I remember. (Irritating, yet true.)

Comment: but it looks so silly on the iPad being so small... hmm.

Comment: Yup. As a suggestion, putting it in an UIActionSheet is sometimes the way to go. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only change the width of a [UIPickerView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html).

However, a common user interface solution is to put the picker into an [UIActionSheet](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (or other similar modal dialog).

Comment: `UIActionSheet is not designed to be subclassed, nor should you add views to its hierarchy`

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to change the size of a UIDatePicker, afaik.

Comment: You can change the width, just not the height. :-)